# How to capture the output of a function and redirect it using a generator in real time?

Tags: python, stdout, capture

I have a function that calls other functions and trains an ML model. I want to capture every output line from that function call stack and redirect it. So, I want something like this:

```
def my_function():
    with train_model() as output:
        yield output
```

I want to display this output on a Flask web page.

Comment: Actual code related to this question would be very helpful.

Comment: What excatly you want to get, show example, also what does `output` contains?